# Rewrite one specific argument with nginx rewrite

Tags: nginx, mod-rewrite

I want to rewrite an argument given via URL on my nginx server from "my_arg" to "my-arg". The problem is that I can't know how many arguments there will be in advance nor the position of these arguments.
I can only know if the arguments is there using :

```
if ($args ~ (.*)my_arg=(.*)) {
    rewrite ....
}
```

But i cannot achieve to only change the name of this argument without changing every others.

Thanks by advance

Answer (score 1):

For anything except HTTP 301/302 redirection you'd better just change an `$args` variable value:

```
if ($args ~ (^|.*&)my_arg=(.*)) {
    set $args $1my-arg=$2;
}
```

If you want to generate a redirect, things will be more complicated. Since any `rewrite` directive performs its own URI matching against some regex pattern, all the `$1`, `$2` and so on variables from previous matching will be overwritten, and you can't match a query part of the URI to get them re-evaluated since `rewrite` directive works with normalized URI that doesn't include a query part. Your only way is to use  [named capture groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html):

```
if ($args ~ (?<prefix>^|.*&)my_arg=(?<suffix>.*)) {
    rewrite ^ $uri${prefix}my-arg=$suffix? <redirect|permanent>;
}
```

Trailing question mark used intentionally since as `rewrite` directive documentation [says](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite),

> If a *replacement* string includes the new request arguments, the previous request arguments are appended after them. If this is undesired, putting a question mark at the end of a replacement string avoids having them appended, for example:
>
> ```
> rewrite ^/users/(.*)$ /show?user=$1? last;
> ```